# query running long due to nested loop

Tags: postgresql

Below query is using nested loop and takes more than an hour to run (the explain is generated by https://explain.depesz.com/ and the query's tables are changed manually by me - so the names will not match). Tables are up to date with stats and vacuum. Estimated values are almost same as actual values i.e. when query was run with explain analyze.

Optimizer generates same plan even with default_statistics_target with 1000. Random-page-cost is 4 and this is postgres v11.7. Was able to force it to use hash join by setting - nestloop to off. But how do I dig deeper to know why its taking nestloop when its apparent that hash join is better.

This keeps happening every now and then for different queries and its fixed by disabling nest loop, I don't want to disable nest loop at database level but also want to be able to figure out the root cause to prevent jobs running long due to bad plan.

```
SELECT ...cols...
   FROM ( SELECT ...cols...
           FROM schemac.cesa cesa
             JOIN ( SELECT cols, row_number() OVER last_ces AS rn
                   FROM schemac.ces ces2
                     JOIN schemaa.pip pip ON ces2.pip_fk = pip.pip_pk
                  WHERE 1 = 1 AND ces2.del_flg = '0' AND pip.del_flg = '0' AND (pip.plan_num_cd !~~ ALL (ARRAY['ZCHP%', 'HHH%', 'NHP%'])) AND ((pip.company_cd = ANY (ARRAY['01', '20'][])) AND ces2.tp_cd <> '1' OR (pip.company_cd <> ALL (ARRAY['01', '20'][])))
                  WINDOW last_ces AS (PARTITION BY (COALESCE(CASE 
                            WHEN ces2.cm_fk = '-2' THEN NULL
                            ELSE ces2.cm_fk
                        END, ces2.hf_member_num_cd)) ORDER BY ces2.expiration_dt DESC, ces2.effective_dt DESC, ces2.source_system_update_dtm DESC)) ces ON cesa.ces_fk = ces.ces_pk
             LEFT JOIN schemac.cm cm ON ces.cm_fk = cm.cm_pk AND cm.del_flg = '0' AND cm.mdm_stt_cd = '1'
             LEFT JOIN schemac.tableb cespf_home ON ces.ces_pk = cespf_home.ces_fk AND cespf_home.del_flg = '0' AND cespf_home.phone_cd = 'HOME' AND cespf_home.aud_sys_cd = 'MHS'
             LEFT JOIN schemac.tableb cespf_other ON ces.ces_pk = cespf_other.ces_fk AND cespf_other.del_flg = '0' AND cespf_other.phone_cd = 'OTHER' AND cespf_other.aud_sys_cd = 'MHS'
             LEFT JOIN schemac.tableb c_alt ON ces.ces_pk = c_alt.ces_fk AND c_alt.del_flg = '0' AND c_alt.phone_cd = 'ALT' AND c_alt.aud_sys_cd = 'MHS'
             LEFT JOIN schemac.tableb cespf_work ON ces.ces_pk = cespf_work.ces_fk AND cespf_work.del_flg = '0' AND cespf_work.phone_cd = 'WORK' AND cespf_work.aud_sys_cd = 'MHS'
             LEFT JOIN schemac.tableb cespf_cellp ON ces.ces_pk = cespf_cellp.ces_fk AND cespf_cellp.del_flg = '0' AND cespf_cellp.phone_cd = 'CELLPHONE' AND cespf_cellp.aud_sys_cd = 'MHS'
             LEFT JOIN schemac.tableb cespf_fax ON ces.ces_pk = cespf_fax.ces_fk AND cespf_fax.del_flg = '0' AND cespf_fax.phone_cd = 'FAX' AND cespf_fax.aud_sys_cd = 'MHS'
          WHERE 1 = 1 AND ces.rn = 1 AND (cesa.address_usage_tp_cd = ANY (ARRAY['HOME', 'ALT'][])) AND cesa.aud_sys_cd = 'ADDR_DOC' AND cesa.del_flg = '0' ) a
  WINDOW wnd_precedence AS (PARTITION BY a.hf_cm_id_cd, a.hf_member_num_cd ORDER BY a.address_ranking, a.address_usage_tp_cd, a.correspondence_ind DESC);;
```

```
WindowAgg  (cost=9977352.670..9978557.800 rows=28356 width=530)
  ->  Sort  (cost=9977352.670..9977423.560 rows=28356 width=450)
          Sort Key: (lima_sierra_five(four_kilo.lima_sierra_three, 'kilo_seven'::character varying)), kilo_lima.tango_three, (CASE WHEN (((mike_yankee_quebec.six_quebec)::text = 'oscar_juliet'::text) AND ((mike_yankee_quebec.mike_yankee_romeo)::text = 'uniform_five'::text)) THEN 1 WHEN ((mike_yankee_quebec.six_quebec)::text = 'tango_bravo'::text) THEN 3 ELSE 4 END), (CASE WHEN ((mike_yankee_quebec.six_quebec)::text = 'tango_bravo'::text) THEN 'six_seven'::text WHEN ((mike_yankee_quebec.six_quebec)::text = 'oscar_juliet'::text) THEN 'three'::text ELSE NULL::text END), mike_yankee_quebec.mike_yankee_romeo DESC
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=3190868.620..9975255.550 rows=28356 width=450)
              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=3190867.930..9199856.270 rows=28356 width=448)
                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=3190867.240..8424811.440 rows=28356 width=429)
                          ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=3190866.550..7649766.610 rows=28356 width=405)
                                ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=3190865.860..6874721.770 rows=28356 width=386)
                                      ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=3190865.170..6099676.940 rows=28356 width=367)
                                            ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=3190864.480..5324632.110 rows=28356 width=348)
                                                  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=3190863.930..5139089.590 rows=28356 width=275)
                                                        ->  Subquery Scan on kilo_lima  (cost=3190863.240..3557449.840 rows=45823 width=170)
                                                                Filter: (kilo_lima.xray_romeo = 1)
                                                              ->  WindowAgg  (cost=3190863.240..3442891.530 rows=9164665 width=524)
                                                                    ->  Sort  (cost=3190863.240..3213774.900 rows=9164665 width=218)
                                                                            Sort Key: (lima_sierra_five(CASE WHEN (kilo_lima2.victor = 'india_hotel'::bpchar) THEN NULL::bpchar ELSE kilo_lima2.victor END, (kilo_lima2.tango_three)::bpchar)), kilo_lima2.uniform_two DESC, kilo_lima2.echo DESC, kilo_lima2.november_oscar DESC
                                                                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=624.570..1160016.380 rows=9164665 width=218)
                                                                                  Hash Cond: (kilo_lima2.zulu_three = four_hotel.whiskey)
                                                                                  Join Filter: ((((four_hotel.uniform_delta)::text = ANY ('kilo_oscar'::text[])) AND ((kilo_lima2.seven_seven)::text <> 'four_uniform'::text)) OR ((four_hotel.uniform_delta)::text <> november_november ('kilo_oscar'::text[])))
                                                                                ->  Seq Scan on quebec_november india_golf  (cost=0.000..1111965.520 rows=9327879 width=253)
                                                                                        Filter: (xray_oscar = 'november_golf'::bpchar)
                                                                                ->  Hash  (cost=550.860..550.860 rows=5897 width=68)
                                                                                      ->  Seq Scan on seven_three four_hotel  (cost=0.000..550.860 rows=5897 width=68)
                                                                                              Filter: ((xray_oscar = 'november_golf'::bpchar) AND ((delta_oscar)::text !~~ november_november ('zulu_five'::text[])))
                                                        ->  Index Scan using lima_four on bravo mike_yankee_quebec  (cost=0.690..34.510 rows=1 width=170)
                                                                Index Cond: (mike_four = kilo_lima.lima_uniform)
                                                                Filter: (((six_quebec)::text = ANY ('foxtrot'::text[])) AND ((xray_papa)::text = 'india_six'::text) AND (xray_oscar = 'november_golf'::bpchar))
                                                  ->  Index Scan using five on delta_echo four_kilo  (cost=0.560..6.540 rows=1 width=138)
                                                          Index Cond: (kilo_lima.victor = six_uniform)
                                                          Filter: ((xray_oscar = 'november_golf'::bpchar) AND ((oscar_lima)::text = 'four_uniform'::text))
                                            ->  Index Scan using xray_charlie on two_papa xray_xray  (cost=0.690..27.320 rows=1 width=84)
                                                    Index Cond: (kilo_lima.lima_uniform = mike_four)
                                                    Filter: ((xray_oscar = 'november_golf'::bpchar) AND ((four_five)::text = 'tango_bravo'::text) AND ((xray_papa)::text = 'yankee'::text))
                                      ->  Index Scan using xray_charlie on two_papa golf_charlie  (cost=0.690..27.320 rows=1 width=84)
                                              Index Cond: (kilo_lima.lima_uniform = mike_four)
                                              Filter: ((xray_oscar = 'november_golf'::bpchar) AND ((four_five)::text = 'india_alpha'::text) AND ((xray_papa)::text = 'yankee'::text))
                                ->  Index Scan using xray_charlie on two_papa india_charlie  (cost=0.690..27.320 rows=1 width=84)
                                        Index Cond: (kilo_lima.lima_uniform = mike_four)
                                        Filter: ((xray_oscar = 'november_golf'::bpchar) AND ((four_five)::text = 'oscar_juliet'::text) AND ((xray_papa)::text = 'yankee'::text))
                          ->  Index Scan using xray_charlie on two_papa golf_two  (cost=0.690..27.320 rows=1 width=89)
                                  Index Cond: (kilo_lima.lima_uniform = mike_four)
                                  Filter: ((xray_oscar = 'november_golf'::bpchar) AND ((four_five)::text = 'quebec_foxtrot'::text) AND ((xray_papa)::text = 'yankee'::text))
                    ->  Index Scan using xray_charlie on two_papa xray_bravo  (cost=0.690..27.320 rows=1 width=84)
                            Index Cond: (kilo_lima.lima_uniform = mike_four)
                            Filter: ((xray_oscar = 'november_golf'::bpchar) AND ((four_five)::text = 'zulu_tango'::text) AND ((xray_papa)::text = 'yankee'::text))
              ->  Index Scan using xray_charlie on two_papa delta_seven  (cost=0.690..27.320 rows=1 width=84)
                      Index Cond: (kilo_lima.lima_uniform = mike_four)
                      Filter: ((xray_oscar = 'november_golf'::bpchar) AND ((four_five)::text = 'two_mike'::text) AND ((xray_papa)::text = 'yankee'::text))
```

Comment: Impossible to say much without `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.

Comment: We would need to see both plans (with enable_nestloop on and with it off), and run under ANALYZE.